# MIT 6.00.1x Set 2 P3 || Almost done and very close, but failed

Tags: python, debugging

First of all, I feel sorry. This is my first time to use this website so I don't know the rules.

I try to show my attempt but I don't know how to do this. I just rewrite the code directly day by day and don't have the saved drafts. I use many methods to work out, but I am fresh to coding and as you know, I keep on going the MIT CS introduction course.

For this problem, I would like to paste the original link but you need to sign in the website first. So I google it and find a Github page which contained the problem. [enter link description here](https://github.com/anarayanan86/MITx-6.00.1x/tree/master/Week_2-_Simple_Programs/Problem_Set_2) The problem set has three problems and I have solved first two of them.

It's about how to calculate credit cards latest monthly payment, and must use **bisection search**.

I have worked out once. However, I can only do one bisection search and then minus 0.01 step to step to approach the result. I show you my code before, here is the only old version which I saved.

```
balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate /12.0
lower_bound = balance / 12.0
upper_bound = (balance * (1 + monthly_interest_rate)**12) / 12.0

def calculate_balance(balance, fixed):
    month = 0
    while month < 12:
        balance = (balance - fixed) * (monthly_interest_rate + 1)
        month += 1
    return balance

while True:
    if calculate_balance(balance, lower_bound) > 0:
        lower_bound = (lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2
    else:
        skipped_answer = lower_bound
        break
#print(skipped_answer)
while True:
    #print(balance, skipped_answer)
    if calculate_balance(balance, skipped_answer) < 0:
        skipped_answer -= 0.01
    else:
        break
print(round(skipped_answer+0.01, 2))
```

Anyway, this code works fine but the grader of edx says my code takes too much time.

So I think out of dual-directed bisection search and it takes me hours again. But this is the limit of my ability. I have no ideas. Here's the code below.

```
balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate /12.0
lower_bound = balance / 12.0
upper_bound = (balance * (1 + monthly_interest_rate)**12) / 12.0

def calculate_balance(balance, fixed):
    month = 0
    while month < 12:
        balance = (balance - fixed) * (monthly_interest_rate + 1)
        month += 1
        balance
    return balance

while True: 
    if abs(calculate_balance(balance, lower_bound) - balance) > 0.01:
        if calculate_balance(balance, lower_bound) > 0:
            mark = lower_bound
            lower_bound = (lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2
        elif calculate_balance(balance, lower_bound) < 0:
            upper_bound = lower_bound
            lower_bound = mark
    else:
        break
print(lower_bound)
```

I don't know why it will be an infinite loop. And how to solve it? What's wrong?

Thinking this for hours. I have tried all the methods that I know.

I worked out all of the exercises by myself and takes me too much time. This time, I know I must get help of experienced people. There must be something I don't know.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Like... debugging the variables, outputting them in every loop to see why the condition does not match like expected,.....???

Comment: Title of question doesn't explain your question. We don't know what you are trying to do with this code which makes debugging harder. And as Nico Haase said, you don't show us your attempts.

Comment: I am sorry for what I don't add some information because it's my first time to use stack overflow. And indeed I tried to test and rewrite my code all days and this version is the best one I could make. I don't know how to edit the question. If I find the way, I'll do better.

Comment: Click the `edit` link under the question.

Comment: Well, I edited it days ago and no reply, sad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't knew is it now of any interest to see my code that works very fast. It is little
bit different then yours:

```
balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
payment = 0
lower = balance/12.0
upper = (balance*(1+annualInterestRate/12)**12)/12.0
lbalance = 0

while payment < balance :
    oldbalance = lbalance
    lbalance = balance
    payment = round((lower + upper)/2,3)


    for i in range(0,12):

        unpaidBalance = lbalance - payment
        interest = unpaidBalance * annualInterestRate / 12.0 
        lbalance = unpaidBalance + interest

    if round(lbalance,2) == 0 or oldbalance == lbalance:
        print('Lowest Payment: ' + str(payment))
        break
    elif lbalance > 0 :
        lower = payment
    else:
        upper = payment
```

Why both of your codes in some cases use bisection and in some don't? This is the main problem.

All the best to all of you
Have a nice day